# Select image from first div only using jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to grab image src from first div with div class and image class, however another div and image also has same class so I am unable to get it.

```js
console.log(
    $("div.DetailSection_content").find("img:first").attr("src")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https:img_url_1" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https:img_url_2" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it will only the `src` for one image when you use `.attr("src")`

in your case `:first` does not do anything based on your code, because you only have 1 image inside each `<div class="DetailSection_content">`

You can do it like this:

```
var imgs = $('div.DetailSection_content img').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src")
}).get();
```

This will return an array of the img src from `$('div.DetailSection_content img')`

**Demo**

```js
var imgs = $('div.DetailSection_content img').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src")
}).get();
console.log(imgs)

console.log(
    $("div.DetailSection_content img").attr("src")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https:img_url1" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https:img_url2" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const src = $('div.DetailSection_content img')[0].src
```

```js
$(() => {

const src = $('.DetailSection_content img')[0].src

console.log(src)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https:img_url_1" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https:img_url_2" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP states that hes able to get the src from the first image, but not from the other images. Also try is a very broad description of a solution.

Comment: I have misread the question my bad

Comment: You still only console the first src out, OP want's both src